# How to show a pointer address with a messagebox in VS 2008 C++

Tags: pointers, formatting, c++-cli, string-formatting, messagebox

I have been trying to show the pointer address in a messagebox and need your experience. Here is the code that kind-of works:

```
int MyVar;
int *PMyVar;
MyVar = 5;
PMyVar = &MyVar;
MessageBox::Show("value of MyVar: \n " + Convert::ToString(&PMyVar), "Pointer value");
```

The running program shows:

```
value of MyVar:
True
```

I am trying to show the address of the pointer, such as 0xfc00 (just a guess) instead of True. How do I show the hexadecimal address of a pointer with MessageBox?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of &PMyVar is `int**`, Convert::ToString() does not have overloads that accepts pointer types.  You'll have to cast it to a supported type.  Pointer values can be 4 or 8 bytes so the best choice is UInt64:

```
  String^ str = String::Format("{0:X8}", (UInt64)&PMyVar);
  MessageBox:Show(str);
```

Using String::Format() like this is called *composite formatting*, the "X" format provides formatting to hexadecimal.  Do favor using the debugger instead of writing this kind of code.

Comment: Just a remark, you should use `System::UIntPtr` instead of `System::UInt64` (and choose X8 or X16 depending on `System::UIntPtr::Size`).

Comment: There's no formatting support built-in for UIntPtr either.  Using UInt64 was intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++, use `std::ostringstream`:

```
int MyVar = 5;
int *PMyVar = &MyVar;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "address of PMyVar: " << &PMyVar;
MessageBox::Show(oss.str().c_str(), "Pointer value");
```

and don't forget to `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: It is not exactly C++ ;)

Comment: @HansPassant: Even in case of C++/CLI with great .NET Framework support, I find the usage of STL fine enough :)

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks for your help!